# Plugin already exist in pom.xml file but still got an error of missing, no dependency information available

Tags: java, maven, jenkins, dependencies

`org.codehaus.mojo:properties-maven-plugin:jar:1.0-alpha-2` already exists in `pom.xml`, but I am still getting a dependency error and the build is failing.

> [ERROR] Plugin org.codehaus.mojo:properties-maven-plugin:1.0-alpha-2
>   or one of its dependencies could not be resolved: Cannot access
>   central (https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2) in offline mode and the
>   artifact org.codehaus.mojo:properties-maven-plugin:jar:1.0-alpha-2 has
>   not been downloaded from it before

Currently I am using `-o` argument in command.

Comment: have you tried passing the -U argument to maven? (for example mvn -U clean install) also there is a 1.0.0 version for that dependency

Comment: I am not using the -U argument, currently I am using -o argument in command, once i remove the -o argument, it's throwing an error

Failed to execute goal on project IBMPCS: Could not resolve dependencies for project com.ibm.pcp:IBMPCS:ear:1.0.2175-202005251619: "Failed to collect dependencies at org.eclipse.birt.runtime:org.eclipse.birt.runtime:jar:4.2.2 -> milyn:flute:jar:1.3: Failed to read artifact descriptor for milyn:flute:jar:1.3: Could not transfer artifact milyn:flute:pom:1.3 from/to central (https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2): Received fatal alert: protocol_version"

Comment: dont use the -o argument, that is for offline mode and you need to get some dependencies based on your log, try with  -U instead of -o

Answer (score 1):

You need to remove the -o option, otherwise maven won't try to download the dependency because you are telling to run on offline mode.

You shall use -o when you don't want to maven to look for dependencies.

Comment: I am using the -U argument instead of -o, below is an error I am facing 

[ERROR] Failed to execute goal on project IBMPCS: Could not resolve dependencies for project com.ibm.pcp:IBMPCS:ear:1.0.2189-202005271423: Failed to collect dependencies at org.eclipse.birt.runtime:org.eclipse.birt.runtime:jar:4.2.2 -> milyn:flute:jar:1.3: Failed to read artifact descriptor for milyn:flute:jar:1.3: Could not transfer artifact milyn:flute:pom:1.3 from/to central (https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2): Received fatal alert: protocol_version -> [Help 1]